# Difference between Infinite Java Stream and Reactor Flux

Tags: java, java-stream, flux, spring-webflux, reactor

I am trying to figure out the conceptual differences between an infinite Stream and an infinite Flux respectively (if there are any).

For that matter, I have come up with the following examples for an infinite Stream/Flux

```
@Test
public void infinteStream() {

  //Prints infinite number of integers
  Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1);
 
  infiniteStream.forEach(System.out::println);
}

@Test
public void infiniteFlux()  {
    
   //Prints infinite number of date strings (every second)
   Flux<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .map(t -> LocalDateTime.now());

    localDateTimeFlux.subscribe(t -> System.out.println(t.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))));
}
```

Regarding these examples, I have the question: Is there an analog for infinteStream() with Flux (and for infinteFlux() with Stream respectively)? And, more generally, are there any differences between an infinite Stream and Flux?

Answer (score 29):

`Stream` and `Flux` are quite different:

- `Stream` is single use, vs. you can subscribe multiple times to `Flux`
- `Stream` is pull based (consuming one element calls for the next one) vs. `Flux` has an hybrid push/pull model where the publisher can push elements but still has to respect backpressure signaled by the consumer
- `Stream` are synchronous sequences vs. `Flux` can represent asynchronous sequences

In example you're generating an infinite sequence of values with `Stream`, they're produced and consumed as fast as possible. In your `Flux` example, you're producing values at a fixed interval (something I'm not sure you can do with `Stream`). With `Flux`, you can also `Flux.generate` sequences without intervals, just like your `Stream` example.

In general, you could consider `Flux` as a mix of `Stream` + `CompletableFuture`, with:

- a lot of powerful operators
- backpressure support
- control over publisher and subscriber behavior
- control over the notion of time (buffering windows of values, adding timeouts and fallbacks, etc)
- something tailored for async sequences fetched over the network (from a database or a remote Web API)

Comment: Dear Brian, thanks for elucidating the differences! I will try out your suggestions with Flux.generate :-)

Comment: in what case you should use streams over flux?

Answer (score 2):

For reference, in the meantime, I have come up with a Stream-Solution for infiniteFlux():

```
@Test 
public void infiniteFluxWithStream()  {

    Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1).peek(x->{
    LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.now();
    t.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    System.out.println(t);
    });

    infiniteStream.forEach(x->{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    });
```

}

This is indeed ugly. However, it shows that in (very) principle, it is possible to rewrite simple Flux-Examples in terms of Streams.